# Como redirecionar após login - Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails4

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  get 'home/inicio'
  root 'login#new'

  scope "/login" do
    get "/acesso", to: "login#create"
    post "/acessorecebendo", to: "login#create"
    get "/sair", to:"login#destroy"
  end

  resources :login
  resources :home
  resources :produtos
  resources :fornecedors

end
```

new.html.erb:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
    <div class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
<% end %>


<div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" action="/login/acessorecebendo" method="post">
      <input type="text" name="login[email]" placeholder="Email"/>
      <input type="password" name="login[senha]" placeholder="Senha"/>
      <button>Cadastrar</button>
      <p class="message">Já é registrado? <a href="#">Login</a></p>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form">
      <input type="text" placeholder="username"/>
      <input type="password" placeholder="password"/>
      <button>login</button>
      <p class="message">Não está registrado <a href="#">Criar uma conta</a></p>
    </form>
    <% if session[:user] %>
        <a href="/login/sair">Sair sessão <%= @user.nome  %> </a>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Login controller:

```
class LoginController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def new
    if session[:user]
      @user = User.find(session[:user])
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Você foi deslogado"
  end


  def create
    user = User.validate(login_params[:email], login_params[:senha])
    if user
      session[:user] = user.id
      redirect_to "/home/inicio", notice: "login feito com sucesso"
    else
      redirect_to "/login/acesso", notice: "Dados incorretos"
    end

  end
  private
  def login_params
    params.require(:login).permit(:email, :senha)
  end
end
```

a página inicial é o login e caso ele valide com sucesso, irá redirecionar para uma outra página renderizada pela action inicio do controller Home.
Não estou sabendo executar isso =\

Comment: Você está usando Devise?

Comment: Não. mas também não saberia como usa-lo

Comment: Oi @MikhaelAraujo use o Devise https://github.com/plataformatec/devise basta instalar a gem e rodar a criação das views e controllers `rails generate devise:install` continue lendo https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/README.md vale muito apena e será muito mais seguro a sua aplicação com o Devise

Comment: @GlaucoRoberto parece interessante mas isso é para um trabalho pequeno de faculdade e não vou me aprofundar com isso.

Comment: Outro motivo para usar Devise. Simplifica muito seu trabalho.

Comment: Qual erro você recebe ao tentar fazer dessa maneira ai?

Comment: Você está usando uma palavra reservada de model chamada "validate". Teria que primeiro trocar essa palavra, depois ver como você está fazendo a pesquisa no model do usuário.